How to programmatically send audio to AirPods when they're not he selected audio device
Let's say my control center is routing the audio to the iPhone speaker or an external Bluetooth speaker. Is there any way I can 'force route' the audio from my app to a nearby airpod (that's connected but not the current chosen output)? Ideally, I'd want my app to send the audio to both the Airpod and the Bluetooth speaker, but I wanna see if I can at least start by force-routing the audio to airpod without it being chosen as the main output source. Open to private APIs since this won't be submitted to the app store. Just a grad school project.
